# KeyPressedEvent not registering

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and trying to implement what should be a pretty straightforward "key pressed" event method, but it doesn't seem to be registering properly.

Here is the declaration in my header file:

```
#include <Qt>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void KeyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);

};
```

and here is the implementation:

```
void MainWindow::KeyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Registered Key Press";
}
```

This is almost exactly what the examples I have seen online look like, so unless there is some connection somewhere I am missing, not sure what the issue would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, as you say, **almost exactly** what the examples show. They should show

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) override;
```

See [QWidget::keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent). Note that **C++ is case sensitive** (K -> k).

Also, I've added the override keyword - then the compiler will tell you if you try to override a function which the compiler doesn't know!

Additional caveats are included in above linked documentation:

- Make sure to call `setFocusPolicy` with an appropriate policy;
- Note also that child widgets can "swallow" events. Meaning that if your main window has any children; and the key press happens inside a child, the child can say "I handle this event, no need to pass it on to my parent". Then your `MainWindow::keyPressEvent` also won't get called; see the corresponding notes in the [`QKeyEvent` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#details); the gist: any child window of your `MainWindow` handling `keyPressEvent` has to `ignore()` the event in order for it to propagate to the parent class.